# Using PHP to Count Rows in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

Can you guys help me with this code.I want to count numbers of down in my comments table but i doesn't seems to works.

```
$count_result =  mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM comments WHERE id=$get_id');
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no prior research nor minimal understanding of the problem being solved

Comment: Is it just me or there really isn't a `mysqli_query` for PHP as indicated [here](http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_query&lang=en&scope=404quickref)?

Comment: Any error are you getting?

Comment: It exists, it is just u

Comment: @Nath mysqli_query is the procedural style of mysqli.  You can also use object oriented.

Comment: @Sahil Mittal no, there is no error, but there is no results too.

Comment: @Roman, how are you using the result object?  mysqli_query doesn't just return the count.  It will return an object for you to manipulate.

Comment: Try your query in mysql command line

Comment: It's great that you're using mysqli_, but why not use prepared statements too?

Comment: Downvoted, because no "normal" description given. What means "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Listen guys, i just wanted to count number of rows in table "comments" and to echo it like echo $count_result;. I don't see where is problem in my code,

Comment: You probably have a few problems.  As Stefan pointed out, you are using single quotes.  As I pointed out, you aren't manipulating the result object.  As Strawberry pointed out, your query is most likely subject to SQL injections because you aren't using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roman try this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id=".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $get_id))) {
    $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I missed that, looks like there are a few problems to be answered from the comments though.  This alone won't achieve his result, but his question was not detailed/researched enough.

Comment: When i use that i got an error   "Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\AiR\bigdocument.php on line 143" Line 143: echo $comment_result;

Comment: @Roman after that code please try `print_r($count_result);` and post results here also remove the echo.

Comment: @Roman, like I said in the comments, you need to manipulate the object returned by mysqli_query.  You need to use one of the fetch functions like http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: The return value of the mysqli_query-call isn't an integer.

Comment: @stefan this is what i got "mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 ) "

Comment: try adding `$row = $count_result->fetch_array();
echo $row[0];`

Comment: error "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\AiR\bigdocument.php on line 145"

Comment: @stefan, you don't want to use an associative array for this.  You want to use a numerical array.  Associative means it would be `$row['COUNT(*)']`

Comment: @stefan that will work but for something like this, fetch_row would probably work best since you only need the 0, not the count(*).  fetch_array will get both and be less efficient.

Comment: @Roman delete the echo line and replace it with print_r($row); paste results here.

Comment: Ah guys i quit, i can't belive it took so much time to resolve problem like this.I thought this will be the easy one ...

Comment: I got this "Array ( [0] => 1 [id] => 1 [1] => 10.4.2014 [post_date] => 10.4.2014 [2] => Prognoza u BiH [news_title] => Prognoza u BiH [3] => SUper sadrzaj [news_content_before] => SUper sadrzaj [4] => color.png [news_title_image] => color.png [5] => Aldin Ahmetovic [author_title] => Aldin Ahmetovic [6] => instagram.png [author_image] => instagram.png [7] => Sadrzaj poslije slike [news_content_after] => Sadrzaj poslije slike ) "

Comment: error "Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\AiR\bigdocument.php on line 148

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\AiR\bigdocument.php on line 148"

Comment: and why i got 4 downvotes on my post. U people are amazing -.-

Comment: @Roman, because this is a site for programmers and it seems like you don't have any basic knowledge surrounding the problem or how to achieve your results.  You are basically asking for someone to write the code for you which is frowned upon.

Comment: Have u seen than i wrote the code but don't know how to set variable?